# horizontal line Specific Row

Tags: tables, hline

How can I remove a hline in a specific column?

I wish the first line did not have the hline

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\centering
\begin{tabular} {|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
     \hline  
     \multirow{2}{5em}{Atividades} & \multicolumn{12}{|c|}{Meses 2019}\\

     \hline

     & Jan & Fev & Mar & Abr & Mai & Jun & Jul & Ago & Set & Out & Nov & Dez  \\
     \hline

     1 & X & X & &  &  & & &  &  & & & \\
     \hline
     2 & & & X & X & &  & &  &  & & &  \\
     \hline
     3 & & & & X  &  &  & &  &  & & & \\
     \hline
     4 & & & & X  & X &  & &  &  & & & \\
     \hline
     5 & & & &  &  & X  & &  &  & & & \\
     \hline
     6 & & & &  &  & X  & &  &  & & & \\
     \hline
\end{tabular}
}
\caption{Cronograma}
\label{tab:Cronograma}
\end{table}
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you don't want `\hline`, just don't type it. *Don't* resize tables.

Comment: your question is not at all clear, your title asks about a hline in a specific row, and the text asks about a column. Also never apply `\resizebox` to tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

probably you looking for the following:

[image]

instead of second `\hline` you should use `\cline{2-13}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{|*{13}{c|}}
     \hline
     \multirow{2}{5em}{Atividades} & \multicolumn{12}{c|}{Meses 2019}\\
     \cline{2-13}  % <---
     & Jan & Fev & Mar & Abr & Mai & Jun & Jul & Ago & Set & Out & Nov & Dez  \\
     \hline
     1 & X & X & &  &  & & &  &  & & & \\
     \hline
     2 & & & X & X & &  & &  &  & & &  \\
     \hline
     3 & & & & X  &  &  & &  &  & & & \\
     \hline
     4 & & & & X  & X &  & &  &  & & & \\
     \hline
     5 & & & &  &  & X  & &  &  & & & \\
     \hline
     6 & & & &  &  & X  & &  &  & & & \\
     \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Cronograma}
\label{tab:Cronograma}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Its works!

Tks!